# Ruby on Rails App deployed to heroku showing "We're sorry, but something went wrong"

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, heroku

#### I'm still quite a newb to this, but to provide some background:

I built up a decent app and followed the proper steps to deploy it to Heroku, when I run the *'Heroku open'* command, I get:

### *"We're sorry, but something went wrong."

(in the opened window.)

#### Hope we can solve this! I've attached the Heroku logs:

```
To git@heroku.com:startupblog.git
   390c9dc..37f5a3d  master -> master
[StartupBlog]$heroku open
Opening startupblog... done
[StartupBlog]$heroku log
 !    `log` is not a heroku command.
 !    Perhaps you meant `logs`.
 !    See `heroku help` for a list of available commands.
[StartupBlog]$heroku logs
2013-02-26T08:25:42+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/actionpack-3.2.11/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/callbacks.rb:28:in `block in call'
2013-02-26T08:25:42+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.2.11/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:405:in `_run__3231968123246769760__call__1023772550130159371__callbacks'
2013-02-26T08:25:42+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.2.11/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:385:in `_run_call_callbacks'
2013-02-26T08:25:42+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.2.11/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:405:in `__run_callback'
2013-02-26T08:25:42+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/actionpack-3.2.11/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/remote_ip.rb:31:in `call'
2013-02-26T08:25:42+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.2.11/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:81:in `run_callbacks'
2013-02-26T08:25:42+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/actionpack-3.2.11/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/callbacks.rb:27:in `call'
2013-02-26T08:25:42+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/actionpack-3.2.11/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/show_exceptions.rb:56:in `call'
2013-02-26T08:25:42+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/actionpack-3.2.11/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/debug_exceptions.rb:16:in `call'
2013-02-26T08:25:42+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.2.11/lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:32:in `call_app'
2013-02-26T08:25:42+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.2.11/lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:22:in `tagged'
2013-02-26T08:25:42+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.2.11/lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:16:in `call'
2013-02-26T08:25:42+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/actionpack-3.2.11/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/request_id.rb:22:in `call'
2013-02-26T08:25:42+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/rack-1.4.5/lib/rack/methodoverride.rb:21:in `call'
2013-02-26T08:25:42+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.2.11/lib/active_support/cache/strategy/local_cache.rb:72:in `call'
2013-02-26T08:25:42+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/rack-1.4.5/lib/rack/lock.rb:15:in `call'
2013-02-26T08:25:42+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/actionpack-3.2.11/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/static.rb:62:in `call'
2013-02-26T08:25:42+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/rack-cache-1.2/lib/rack/cache/context.rb:136:in `forward'
2013-02-26T08:25:42+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.2.11/lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:16:in `block in call'
2013-02-26T08:25:42+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/rack-1.4.5/lib/rack/runtime.rb:17:in `call'
2013-02-26T08:25:42+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/rack-cache-1.2/lib/rack/cache/context.rb:185:in `lookup'
2013-02-26T08:25:42+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2013-02-26T08:25:42+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/rack-cache-1.2/lib/rack/cache/context.rb:245:in `fetch'
2013-02-26T08:25:42+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/rack-cache-1.2/lib/rack/cache/context.rb:66:in `call!'
2013-02-26T08:25:42+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/rack-cache-1.2/lib/rack/cache/context.rb:51:in `call'
2013-02-26T08:25:42+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.2.11/lib/rails/engine.rb:479:in `call'
2013-02-26T08:25:42+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.2.11/lib/rails/application.rb:223:in `call'
2013-02-26T08:25:42+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.2.11/lib/rails/rack/log_tailer.rb:17:in `call'
2013-02-26T08:25:42+00:00 app[web.1]:   /usr/local/lib/ruby/1.9.1/webrick/httpserver.rb:70:in `run'
2013-02-26T08:25:42+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2013-02-26T08:25:42+00:00 app[web.1]:   /usr/local/lib/ruby/1.9.1/webrick/httpserver.rb:111:in `service'
2013-02-26T08:25:42+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/rack-1.4.5/lib/rack/content_length.rb:14:in `call'
2013-02-26T08:25:42+00:00 app[web.1]:   /usr/local/lib/ruby/1.9.1/webrick/server.rb:183:in `block in start_thread'
2013-02-26T08:25:42+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/rack-1.4.5/lib/rack/handler/webrick.rb:59:in `service'
2013-02-26T08:30:59+00:00 heroku[slugc]: Slug compilation started
2013-02-26T08:31:30+00:00 heroku[api]: Release v7 created by anthony.panepinto101@gmail.com
2013-02-26T08:31:30+00:00 heroku[api]: Deploy 37f5a3d by anthony.panepinto101@gmail.com
2013-02-26T08:31:30+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from up to starting
2013-02-26T08:31:31+00:00 heroku[slugc]: Slug compilation finished
2013-02-26T08:31:32+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Starting process with command `bundle exec rails server -p 41761`
2013-02-26T08:31:34+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Stopping all processes with SIGTERM
2013-02-26T08:31:35+00:00 app[web.1]: [2013-02-26 08:31:35] ERROR SignalException: SIGTERM
2013-02-26T08:31:35+00:00 app[web.1]:   /usr/local/lib/ruby/1.9.1/webrick/server.rb:90:in `select'
2013-02-26T08:31:36+00:00 app[web.1]: DEPRECATION WARNING: You have Rails 2.3-style plugins in vendor/plugins! Support for these plugins will be removed in Rails 4.0. Move them out and bundle them in your Gemfile, or fold them in to your app as lib/myplugin/* and config/initializers/myplugin.rb. See the release notes for more on this: http://weblog.rubyonrails.org/2012/1/4/rails-3-2-0-rc2-has-been-released. (called from <top (required)> at /app/config/environment.rb:5)
2013-02-26T08:31:36+00:00 app[web.1]: DEPRECATION WARNING: You have Rails 2.3-style plugins in vendor/plugins! Support for these plugins will be removed in Rails 4.0. Move them out and bundle them in your Gemfile, or fold them in to your app as lib/myplugin/* and config/initializers/myplugin.rb. See the release notes for more on this: http://weblog.rubyonrails.org/2012/1/4/rails-3-2-0-rc2-has-been-released. (called from <top (required)> at /app/config/environment.rb:5)
2013-02-26T08:31:40+00:00 app[web.1]: [2013-02-26 08:31:40] INFO  WEBrick 1.3.1
2013-02-26T08:31:40+00:00 app[web.1]: [2013-02-26 08:31:40] INFO  ruby 1.9.2 (2011-07-09) [x86_64-linux]
2013-02-26T08:31:40+00:00 app[web.1]: [2013-02-26 08:31:40] INFO  WEBrick::HTTPServer#start: pid=2 port=41761
2013-02-26T08:31:41+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to up
2013-02-26T08:31:45+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Error R12 (Exit timeout) -> At least one process failed to exit within 10 seconds of SIGTERM
2013-02-26T08:31:45+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Stopping remaining processes with SIGKILL
2013-02-26T08:31:46+00:00 app[web.1]: => Call with -d to detach
2013-02-26T08:31:46+00:00 app[web.1]: => Ctrl-C to shutdown server
2013-02-26T08:31:46+00:00 app[web.1]: => Booting WEBrick
2013-02-26T08:31:46+00:00 app[web.1]: => Rails 3.2.11 application starting in production on http://0.0.0.0:41761
2013-02-26T08:31:46+00:00 app[web.1]: Started GET "/" for 174.95.207.136 at 2013-02-26 08:31:46 +0000
2013-02-26T08:31:47+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 137
2013-02-26T08:31:47+00:00 app[web.1]: Connecting to database specified by DATABASE_URL
2013-02-26T08:31:47+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activerecord-3.2.11/lib/active_record/query_cache.rb:67:in `rescue in call'
2013-02-26T08:31:47+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path=/ host=startupblog.herokuapp.com fwd="174.95.207.136" dyno=web.1 queue=0 wait=0ms connect=2ms service=1011ms status=500 bytes=643
2013-02-26T08:31:47+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.2.11/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:385:in `_run_call_callbacks'
2013-02-26T08:31:47+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2013-02-26T08:31:47+00:00 app[web.1]: ActiveRecord::ConnectionNotEstablished (ActiveRecord::ConnectionNotEstablished):
2013-02-26T08:31:47+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activerecord-3.2.11/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:410:in `retrieve_connection'
2013-02-26T08:31:47+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activerecord-3.2.11/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_specification.rb:171:in `retrieve_connection'
2013-02-26T08:31:47+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activerecord-3.2.11/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_specification.rb:145:in `connection'
2013-02-26T08:31:47+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/actionpack-3.2.11/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/request_id.rb:22:in `call'
2013-02-26T08:31:47+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/rack-1.4.5/lib/rack/methodoverride.rb:21:in `call'
2013-02-26T08:31:47+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/actionpack-3.2.11/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/callbacks.rb:28:in `block in call'
2013-02-26T08:31:47+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/actionpack-3.2.11/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/static.rb:62:in `call'
2013-02-26T08:31:47+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundl
e/ruby/1.9.1/gems/rack-cache-1.2/lib/rack/cache/context.rb:51:in `call'
2013-02-26T08:31:47+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.2.11/lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:32:in `call_app'
2013-02-26T08:31:47+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/rack-cache-1.2/lib/rack/cache/context.rb:136:in `forward'
2013-02-26T08:31:47+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/rack-cache-1.2/lib/rack/cache/context.rb:66:in `call!'
2013-02-26T08:31:47+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.2.11/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:405:in `_run__646234206873509914__call__2059469811213840144__callbacks'
2013-02-26T08:31:47+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/actionpack-3.2.11/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/debug_exceptions.rb:16:in `call'
2013-02-26T08:31:47+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/rack-1.4.5/lib/rack/runtime.rb:17:in `call'
2013-02-26T08:31:47+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.2.11/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:405:in `__run_callback'
2013-02-26T08:31:47+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/rack-1.4.5/lib/rack/handler/webrick.rb:59:in `service'
2013-02-26T08:31:47+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/rack-1.4.5/lib/rack/lock.rb:15:in `call'
2013-02-26T08:31:47+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/actionpack-3.2.11/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/remote_ip.rb:31:in `call'
2013-02-26T08:31:47+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.2.11/lib/rails/rack/log_tailer.rb:17:in `call'
2013-02-26T08:31:47+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/rack-1.4.5/lib/rack/content_length.rb:14:in `call'
2013-02-26T08:31:47+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.2.11/lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:16:in `block in call'
2013-02-26T08:31:47+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activerecord-3.2.11/lib/active_record/query_cache.rb:61:in `call'
2013-02-26T08:31:47+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activerecord-3.2.11/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:479:in `call'
2013-02-26T08:31:47+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.2.11/lib/rails/engine.rb:479:in `call'
2013-02-26T08:31:47+00:00 app[web.1]:   /usr/local/lib/ruby/1.9.1/webrick/httpserver.rb:111:in `service'
2013-02-26T08:31:47+00:00 app[web.1]:   /usr/local/lib/ruby/1.9.1/webrick/httpserver.rb:70:in `run'
2013-02-26T08:31:47+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/actionpack-3.2.11/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/callbacks.rb:27:in `call'
2013-02-26T08:31:47+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.2.11/lib/active_support/cache/strategy/local_cache.rb:72:in `call'
2013-02-26T08:31:47+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/rack-cache-1.2/lib/rack/cache/context.rb:185:in `lookup'
2013-02-26T08:31:47+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/rack-cache-1.2/lib/rack/cache/context.rb:245:in `fetch'
2013-02-26T08:31:47+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.2.11/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:81:in `run_callbacks'
2013-02-26T08:31:47+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.2.11/lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:22:in `tagged'
2013-02-26T08:31:47+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2013-02-26T08:31:47+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.2.11/lib/rails/application.rb:223:in `call'
2013-02-26T08:31:47+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/actionpack-3.2.11/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/show_exceptions.rb:56:in `call'
2013-02-26T08:31:47+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.2.11/lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:16:in `call'
2013-02-26T08:31:47+00:00 app[web.1]:   /usr/local/lib/ruby/1.9.1/webrick/server.rb:183:in `block in start_thread'
2013-02-26T08:31:47+00:00 app[web.1]:
```

Gemfile contents:

```
source 'https://rubygems.org'

gem 'rails', '3.2.11'

group :development do
  gem 'sqlite3', '1.3.5'
end


# Gems used only for assets and not required
# in production environments by default.
group :assets do
  gem 'sass-rails',   '3.2.5'
  gem 'bootstrap-sass', '~> 2.3.0.1'
  gem 'coffee-rails', '3.2.2'

  gem 'uglifier', '1.2.3'
end

gem 'jquery-rails', '2.0.2'
```

Comment: what db  do you have in gemfile?

Comment: ok you don;t have any db in production

Comment: Please change the question's title to something more meaningful. Keep in mind the title may help some user in the future to solve similar problems.

Comment: @IvayloStrandjev just edited the title. looks like a rogue user

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should create a production database (probably pg) and then initiate the database. You should probably run `heroku run rake db:migrate`