# Heroku error "We're sorry, but something went wrong"

Tags: ruby, heroku

I have a problem with publish my ROR project with Heroku.com service...
I have done all steps from this [tutrial](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/ruby)

but when I am running comand "heroku open" I have an error "We're sorry, but something went wrong", so what I'm doing wrong?

I have been migrated database, but i think this error is connected whith database, here is heroku log:

```
    2013-05-18T12:33:19.546366+00:00 heroku[slugc]: Slug compilation started
2013-05-18T12:34:56.655486+00:00 heroku[api]: Scale to web=1 by vladimir90@inbox.lv
2013-05-18T12:34:57.187082+00:00 heroku[api]: Attach HEROKU_POSTGRESQL_COPPER resource by vladimir90@inbox.lv
2013-05-18T12:34:57.224557+00:00 heroku[api]: Release v3 created by vladimir90@inbox.lv
2013-05-18T12:34:57.308368+00:00 heroku[api]: Add DATABASE_URL config by vladimir90@inbox.lv
2013-05-18T12:34:57.349978+00:00 heroku[api]: Release v4 created by vladimir90@inbox.lv
2013-05-18T12:34:57.408192+00:00 heroku[api]: Add  config by vladimir90@inbox.lv
2013-05-18T12:34:57.442261+00:00 heroku[api]: Release v5 created by vladimir90@inbox.lv
2013-05-18T12:34:57.493006+00:00 heroku[api]: Deploy fe74901 by vladimir90@inbox.lv
2013-05-18T12:34:57.519764+00:00 heroku[api]: Release v6 created by vladimir90@inbox.lv
2013-05-18T12:34:57.570144+00:00 heroku[api]: Deploy fe74901 by vladimir90@inbox.lv
2013-05-18T12:34:57.994564+00:00 heroku[slugc]: Slug compilation finished
2013-05-18T12:34:59.186250+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Starting process with command `bundle exec thin start -R config.ru -e $RAILS_ENV -p 28759`
2013-05-18T12:34:59.616410+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Starting process with command `bundle exec thin start -R config.ru -e $RAILS_ENV -p 50832`
2013-05-18T12:35:01.755960+00:00 app[web.1]: DEPRECATION WARNING: You have Rails 2.3-style plugins in vendor/plugins! Support for these plugins will be removed in Rails 4.0. Move them out and bundle them in your Gemfile, or fold them in to your app as lib/myplugin/* and config/initializers/myplugin.rb. See the release notes for more on this: http://weblog.rubyonrails.org/2012/1/4/rails-3-2-0-rc2-has-been-released. (called from <top (required)> at /app/config/environment.rb:5)
2013-05-18T12:35:01.755960+00:00 app[web.1]: DEPRECATION WARNING: You have Rails 2.3-style plugins in vendor/plugins! Support for these plugins will be removed in Rails 4.0. Move them out and bundle them in your Gemfile, or fold them in to your app as lib/myplugin/* and config/initializers/myplugin.rb. See the release notes for more on this: http://weblog.rubyonrails.org/2012/1/4/rails-3-2-0-rc2-has-been-released. (called from <top (required)> at /app/config/environment.rb:5)
2013-05-18T12:35:01.756255+00:00 app[web.1]: DEPRECATION WARNING: You have Rails 2.3-style plugins in vendor/plugins! Support for these plugins will be removed in Rails 4.0. Move them out and bundle them in your Gemfile, or fold them in to your app as lib/myplugin/* and config/initializers/myplugin.rb. See the release notes for more on this: http://weblog.rubyonrails.org/2012/1/4/rails-3-2-0-rc2-has-been-released. (called from <top (required)> at /app/config/environment.rb:5)
2013-05-18T12:35:03.393994+00:00 app[web.1]: DEPRECATION WARNING: You have Rails 2.3-style plugins in vendor/plugins! Support for these plugins will be removed in Rails 4.0. Move them out and bundle them in your Gemfile, or fold them in to your app as lib/myplugin/* and config/initializers/myplugin.rb. See the release notes for more on this: http://weblog.rubyonrails.org/2012/1/4/rails-3-2-0-rc2-has-been-released. (called from <top (required)> at /app/config/environment.rb:5)
2013-05-18T12:35:03.392166+00:00 app[web.1]: DEPRECATION WARNING: You have Rails 2.3-style plugins in vendor/plugins! Support for these plugins will be removed in Rails 4.0. Move them out and bundle them in your Gemfile, or fold them in to your app as lib/myplugin/* and config/initializers/myplugin.rb. See the release notes for more on this: http://weblog.rubyonrails.org/2012/1/4/rails-3-2-0-rc2-has-been-released. (called from <top (required)> at /app/config/environment.rb:5)
2013-05-18T12:35:03.394482+00:00 app[web.1]: DEPRECATION WARNING: You have Rails 2.3-style plugins in vendor/plugins! Support for these plugins will be removed in Rails 4.0. Move them out and bundle them in your Gemfile, or fold them in to your app as lib/myplugin/* and config/initializers/myplugin.rb. See the release notes for more on this: http://weblog.rubyonrails.org/2012/1/4/rails-3-2-0-rc2-has-been-released. (called from <top (required)> at /app/config/environment.rb:5)
2013-05-18T12:35:03.622905+00:00 app[web.1]: Connecting to database specified by DATABASE_URL
2013-05-18T12:35:05.302411+00:00 app[web.1]: >> Maximum connections set to 1024
2013-05-18T12:35:05.300907+00:00 app[web.1]: >> Thin web server (v1.5.1 codename Straight Razor)
2013-05-18T12:35:05.302411+00:00 app[web.1]: >> Listening on 0.0.0.0:28759, CTRL+C to stop
2013-05-18T12:35:05.630396+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to up
2013-05-18T12:35:07.084035+00:00 app[web.1]: Connecting to database specified by DATABASE_URL
2013-05-18T12:35:09.555272+00:00 app[web.1]: >> Thin web server (v1.5.1 codename Straight Razor)
2013-05-18T12:35:09.555449+00:00 app[web.1]: >> Maximum connections set to 1024
2013-05-18T12:35:09.555590+00:00 app[web.1]: >> Listening on 0.0.0.0:50832, CTRL+C to stop
2013-05-18T12:35:13.720603+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Stopping all processes with SIGTERM
2013-05-18T12:35:16.014857+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 0
2013-05-18T12:38:10.548264+00:00 heroku[api]: Scale to web=1 by vladimir90@inbox.lv
2013-05-18T12:39:35.438944+00:00 heroku[api]: Starting process with command `bundle exec rake db:migrate` by vladimir90@inbox.lv
2013-05-18T12:39:38.857061+00:00 heroku[run.2831]: Awaiting client
2013-05-18T12:39:38.879446+00:00 heroku[run.2831]: Starting process with command `bundle exec rake db:migrate`
2013-05-18T12:39:40.061754+00:00 heroku[run.2831]: State changed from starting to up
2013-05-18T12:40:10.270266+00:00 heroku[run.2831]: State changed from up to complete
2013-05-18T12:40:10.255030+00:00 heroku[run.2831]: Process exited with status 1
2013-05-18T12:41:05.857726+00:00 heroku[api]: Starting process with command `bundle exec rake db:drop` by vladimir90@inbox.lv
2013-05-18T12:41
:13.440682+00:00 heroku[run.3156]: Awaiting client
2013-05-18T12:41:13.496798+00:00 heroku[run.3156]: Starting process with command `bundle exec rake db:drop`
2013-05-18T12:41:14.317214+00:00 heroku[run.3156]: State changed from starting to up
2013-05-18T12:41:18.771015+00:00 heroku[run.3156]: Process exited with status 0
2013-05-18T12:41:18.786550+00:00 heroku[run.3156]: State changed from up to complete
2013-05-18T12:41:56.728233+00:00 heroku[api]: Starting process with command `bundle exec rake db:migrate` by vladimir90@inbox.lv
2013-05-18T12:41:58.722421+00:00 heroku[run.2678]: Awaiting client
2013-05-18T12:41:58.743284+00:00 heroku[run.2678]: Starting process with command `bundle exec rake db:migrate`
2013-05-18T12:42:05.452581+00:00 heroku[run.2678]: Process exited with status 1
2013-05-18T12:42:05.473489+00:00 heroku[run.2678]: State changed from up to complete
2013-05-18T12:41:59.493538+00:00 heroku[run.2678]: State changed from starting to up
2013-05-18T12:43:44.162348+00:00 heroku[api]: Starting process with command `db:migrate` by vladimir90@inbox.lv
2013-05-18T12:43:48.582497+00:00 heroku[run.6317]: Awaiting client
2013-05-18T12:43:48.595152+00:00 heroku[run.6317]: Starting process with command `db:migrate`
2013-05-18T12:43:50.136438+00:00 heroku[run.6317]: Process exited with status 127
2013-05-18T12:43:50.153625+00:00 heroku[run.6317]: State changed from starting to complete
2013-05-18T12:43:58.600834+00:00 heroku[run.6317]: Stopping process with SIGKILL
2013-05-18T12:43:58.600579+00:00 heroku[run.6317]: Error R99 (Platform error) -> Failed to launch the dyno within 10 seconds
2013-05-18T12:44:04.921978+00:00 heroku[api]: Starting process with command `bundle exec rake db:migrate` by vladimir90@inbox.lv
2013-05-18T12:44:07.469110+00:00 heroku[run.1605]: Awaiting client
2013-05-18T12:44:07.493587+00:00 heroku[run.1605]: Starting process with command `bundle exec rake db:migrate`
2013-05-18T12:44:08.483461+00:00 heroku[run.1605]: State changed from starting to up
2013-05-18T12:44:20.496304+00:00 heroku[run.1605]: State changed from up to complete
2013-05-18T12:44:20.483493+00:00 heroku[run.1605]: Process exited with status 1
2013-05-18T12:44:28.137123+00:00 app[web.1]: Started GET "/" for 78.154.136.249 at 2013-05-18 12:44:28 +0000
2013-05-18T12:44:28.203884+00:00 app[web.1]: Completed 500 Internal Server Error in 4ms
2013-05-18T12:44:28.205394+00:00 app[web.1]:                                         ^
2013-05-18T12:44:28.208346+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path=/ host=murmuring-sierra-7529.herokuapp.com fwd="78.154.136.249" dyno=web.1 connect=5ms service=82ms status=500 bytes=643
2013-05-18T12:44:28.205394+00:00 app[web.1]:                      pg_get_expr(d.adbin, d.adrelid), a.attnotnull, a.atttypid, a.atttypmod
2013-05-18T12:44:28.199798+00:00 app[web.1]: Processing by CatalogController#index as HTML
2013-05-18T12:44:28.205394+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2013-05-18T12:44:28.205394+00:00 app[web.1]: LINE 5:              WHERE a.attrelid = '"carts"'::regclass
2013-05-18T12:44:28.205670+00:00 app[web.1]:   app/controllers/application_controller.rb:21:in `initialize_cart'
2013-05-18T12:44:28.205394+00:00 app[web.1]:                 ON a.attrelid = d.adrelid AND a.attnum = d.adnum
2013-05-18T12:44:28.205670+00:00 app[web.1]:              ORDER BY a.attnum
2013-05-18T12:44:28.205394+00:00 app[web.1]:               FROM pg_attribute a LEFT JOIN pg_attrdef d
2013-05-18T12:44:28.205394+00:00 app[web.1]:                AND a.attnum > 0 AND NOT a.attisdropped
2013-05-18T12:44:28.205670+00:00 app[web.1]: ):
2013-05-18T12:44:28.205394+00:00 app[web.1]: :             SELECT a.attname, format_type(a.atttypid, a.atttypmod),
2013-05-18T12:44:28.205394+00:00 app[web.1]: ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid (PG::Error: ERROR:  relation "carts" does not exist
2013-05-18T12:44:28.205394+00:00 app[web.1]:              WHERE a.attrelid = '"carts"'::regclass
2013-05-18T12:44:28.205670+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2013-05-18T12:44:28.205670+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2013-05-18T12:44:28.419883+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path=/favicon.ico host=murmuring-sierra-7529.herokuapp.com fwd="78.154.136.249" dyno=web.1 connect=0ms service=8ms status=200 bytes=0
```

and I was readed this post - [Ruby on Rails App deployed to heroku showing "We're sorry, but something went wrong"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15084668/were-sorry-but-something-went-wrong) , but in my case it doesn't helps for me =(
So can anyone help me with my problem?

**UPD 1:**
here is create_cart_items.rb code:

```
class CreateCartItems < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    create_table :cart_items do |t|
      t.column :book_id, :integer
      t.column :cart_id, :integer
      t.column :price, :float
      t.column :amount, :integer
      t.column :created_at, :datetime
    end
  end
end
```

**UPD 2**: here is a db:migrate trace:

```
Running `rake db:migrate --trace` attached to terminal... up, run.7697
DEPRECATION WARNING: You have Rails 2.3-style plugins in vendor/plugins! Support for these plugins will be removed in Rails 4.0. Move them out and bundle them in your Gemfile, or fold them in to your app as lib/myplugin/* and config/initializers/myplugin.rb. See the release notes for more on this: http://weblog.rubyonrails.org/2012/1/4/rails-3-2-0-rc2-has-been-released. (called from <top (required)> at /app/Rakefile:7)
DEPRECATION WARNING: You have Rails 2.3-style plugins in vendor/plugins! Support for these plugins will be removed in Rails 4.0. Move them out and bundle them in your Gemfile, or fold them in to your app as lib/myplugin/* and config/initializers/myplugin.rb. See the release notes for more on this: http://weblog.rubyonrails.org/2012/1/4/rails-3-2-0-rc2-has-been-released. (called from <top (required)> at /app/Rakefile:7)
DEPRECATION WARNING: You have Rails 2.3-style plugins in vendor/plugins! Support for these plugins will be removed in Rails 4.0. Move them out and bundle them in your Gemfile, or fold them in to your app as lib/myplugin/* and config/initializers/myplugin.rb. See the release notes for more on this: http://weblog.rubyonrails.org/2012/1/4/rails-3-2-0-rc2-has-been-released. (called from <top (required)> at /app/Rakefile:7)
** Invoke db:migrate (first_time)
** Invoke environment (first_time)
** Execute environment
Connecting to database specified by DATABASE_URL
** Invoke db:load_config (first_time)
** Execute db:load_config
** Execute db:migrate
Migrating to CreateAuthors (20130302171259)
Migrating to CreatePublishers (20130302185948)
Migrating to CreateBooksAndAuthorsBooks (20130302195412)
==  CreateBooksAndAuthorsBooks: migrating =====================================
-- create_table(:books)
NOTICE:  CREATE TABLE will create implicit sequence "books_id_seq" for serial column "books.id"
NOTICE:  CREATE TABLE / PRIMARY KEY will create implicit index "books_pkey" for table "books"
   -> 0.0557s
-- create_table(:authors_books, {:id=>false})
   -> 0.0031s
-- Adding foreign keys
-- execute("CREATE TRIGGER fk_bk_authors BEFORE DELETE ON authors FOR EACH ROW BEGIN DELETE FROM authors_books WHERE author_id = OLD.id; END")
rake aborted!
An error has occurred, this and all later migrations canceled:

PG::Error: ERROR:  syntax error at or near "BEGIN"
LINE 1: ..._bk_authors BEFORE DELETE ON authors FOR EACH ROW BEGIN DELE...
                                                             ^
: CREATE TRIGGER fk_bk_authors BEFORE DELETE ON authors FOR EACH ROW BEGIN DELETE FROM authors_books WHERE author_id = OLD.id; END/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activerecord-3.2.11/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/postgresql_adapter.rb:652:in `exec'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activerecord-3.2.11/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/postgresql_adapter.rb:652:in `block in execute'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activerecord-3.2.11/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract_adapter.rb:280:in `block in log'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.2.11/lib/active_support/notifications/instrumenter.rb:20:in `instrument'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activerecord-3.2.11/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract_adapter.rb:275:in `log'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activerecord-3.2.11/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/postgresql_adapter.rb:651:in `execute'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activerecord-3.2.11/lib/active_record/migration.rb:466:in `block in method_missing'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activerecord-3.2.11/lib/active_record/migration.rb:438:in `block in say_with_time'
/usr/local/lib/ruby/1.9.1/benchmark.rb:295:in `measure'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activerecord-3.2.11/lib/active_record/migration.rb:438:in `say_with_time'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activerecord-3.2.11/lib/active_record/migration.rb:458:in `method_missing'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activerecord-3.2.11/lib/active_record/migration.rb:334:in `method_missing'
/app/db/migrate/20130302195412_create_books_and_authors_books.rb:20:in `block in up'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activerecord-3.2.11/lib/active_record/migration.rb:438:in `block in say_with_time'
/usr/local/lib/ruby/1.9.1/benchmark.rb:295:in `measure'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activerecord-3.2.11/lib/active_record/migration.rb:438:in `say_with_time'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activerecord-3.2.11/lib/active_record/migration.rb:334:in `method_missing'
/app/db/migrate/20130302195412_create_books_and_authors_books.rb:15:in `up'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activerecord-3.2.11/lib/active_record/migration.rb:370:in `up'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activerecord-3.2.11/lib/active_record/migration.rb:410:in `block (2 levels) in migrate'
/usr/local/lib/ruby/1.9.1/benchmark.rb:295:in `measure'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activerecord-3.2.11/lib/active_record/migration.rb:410:in `block in migrate'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activerecord-3.2.11/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:129:in `with_connection'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activerecord-3.2.11/lib/active_record/migration.rb:389:in `migrate'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activerecord-3.2.11/lib/active_record/migration.rb:528:in `migrate'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activerecord-3.2.11/lib/active_record/migration.rb:720:in `block (2 levels) in migrate'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activerecord-3.2.11/lib/active_record/migration.rb:775:in `call'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activerecord-3.2.11/lib/active_record/migration.rb:775:in `block in ddl_transaction'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activerecord-3.2.11/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/database_statements.rb:192:in `transaction'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activerecord-3.2.11/lib/active_record/transactions.rb:208:in `transaction'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activerecord-3.2.11/lib/active_record/migration.rb:775:in `ddl_transaction'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activerecord-3.2.11/lib/active_record/migration.rb:719:in `block in migrate'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activerecord-3.2.11/lib/active_record/migration.rb:700:in `each'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activerecord-3.2.11/lib/active_record/migration.rb:700:in `migrate'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activerecord-3.2.11/lib/active_record/migration.rb:570:in `up'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activerecord-3.2.11/lib/active_record/migration.rb:551:in `migrate'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activerecord-3.2.11/lib/active_record/railties/databases.rake:179:in `block (2 levels) in <top (required)>'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/rake-10.0.4/lib/rake/task.rb:246:in `call'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/rake-10.0.4/lib/rake/task.rb:246:in `block in execute'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/rake-10.0.4/lib/rake/task.rb:241:in `each'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/rake-10.0.4/lib/rake/task.rb:241:in `execute'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/rake-10.0.4/lib/rake/task.rb:184:in `block in invoke_with_call_chain'
/usr/local/lib/ruby/1.9.1/monitor.rb:201:in `mon_synchronize'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/rake-10.0.4/lib/rake/task.rb:177:in `invoke_with_call_chain'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/rake-10.0.4/lib/rake/task.rb:170:in `invoke'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/rake-10.0.4/lib/rake/application.rb:143:in `invoke_task'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/rake-10.0.4/lib/rake/application.rb:101:in `block (2 levels) in top_level'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/rake-10.0.4/lib/rake/application.rb:101:in `each'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/rake-10.0.4/lib/rake/application.rb:101:in `block in top_level'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/rake-10.0.4/lib/rake/application.rb:110:in `run_with_threads'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/rake-10.0.4/lib/rake/application.rb:95:in `top_level'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/rake-10.0.4/lib/rake/application.rb:73:in `block in run'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/rake-10.0.4/lib/rake/application.rb:160:in `standard_exception_handling'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/rake-10.0.4/lib/rake/application.rb:70:in `run'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/rake-10.0.4/bin/rake:33:in `<top (required)>'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/bin/rake:19:in `load'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/bin/rake:19:in `<main>'
Tasks: TOP => db:migrate
```

**UPD3**: application_controller.rb code:

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
  before_filter :set_locale
  helper :all # include all helpers, all the time
  protect_from_forgery :only => [:create, :update, :destroy]
  private
  def set_locale
    accept_lang = request.env['HTTP_ACCEPT_LANGUAGE']
    accept_lang = accept_lang.blank? ? nil : accept_lang[/[^,;]+/]
    locale = params[:locale] || session[:locale] || accept_lang ||DEFAULT_LOCALE
    begin
      I18n.locale = locale
      session[:locale] = locale
    rescue
          I18n.locale = DEFAULT_LOCALE
    end
  end
  def initialize_cart
    if session[:cart_id] and Cart.exists?(session[:cart_id])
      @cart = Cart.find(session[:cart_id])
    else
      @cart = Cart.create
      session[:cart_id] = @cart.id
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: could you show app/controllers/application_controller.rb line 21 ? looks like you have problem there

Comment: The error near the bottom: "ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid (PG::Error: ERROR:  relation "carts" does not exist"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### Summary:

Do `heroku run rake db:migrate`

#### Details:

It looks like the carts table does not exist.

Please show the rails migration that creates it.

Are you sure the migration has run on Heroku, not just locally?

If you do a `heroku run rake db:migrate` what do you get?

Comment: "Are you sure the migration has run on Heroku, not just locally?" and how can i know is this locally or on Heroku server?

Comment: looks like an error in your migration code `PG::Error: ERROR:  syntax error at or near "BEGIN"`